# Scientists developed the first computer program. It took 25 minutes to complete one calculation. It refers to...?

Tags: pronouns

What does the pronoun *it* refer to in this paragraph?

> During that decade, scientists in England developed the first computer program. It took 25 minutes to complete one calculation.

Does it refer to "computer program" or" to complete one calculation "?

Comment: Does it refer to "computer program" or" to complete one calculation "?

Comment: What do you think?

Comment: There is no difference in meaning whether "it" refers to the computer or is a dummy pronoun used to express a time.

Comment: These sentences are so atrociously ignorant that nothing refers to anything.

Comment: It's a needless question. Just say *...which took 25 minutes to complete one calculation.*

Comment: Interesting question. 'It' could be a dummy pronoun, like 'there' in "There is nothing to worry about". Or it could be explicitly referring to the context  in the previous sentence. It's not really referring, like a real pronoun would, to 'to complete one calculation'. "It takes" is just an idiom - English syntax just -has- to have a subject spelled out there so it fills it with something, the 'it'. So if forced to give its referent it would be completing one calculation. If you said "It was so slow that..." then 'it' refers to the program. That's why it feels ambiguous.

Comment: It could go either way, but the most idiomatic read is that your *it* is an anticipatory *it* — standing in for *to complete one calculation*: *To complete one calculation took 25 minutes.* That's just how it tends to go with *it* + *takes*.